# unique ID for customer protection CMS

Tags: php

I develloped a standalone flatfile based cms. Now in order to protect my code from being stolen by clients, i've been looking arround but didn't find much usefull to protect my code. I have found [ioncube](http://www.ioncube.com/online_encoder.php), but i don't really like that...

I am wondering if it is possible to create a file within  the cms, a php file, with a unique ID for every sale i made. That file transmits a signal to a webserver with that ID. So i can tract the online versions of my cms. If it gets copied i will see 2 or more versions with that ID online and i know which company or user distributed my code. But is it possible to make a cms dependable on that file... if a user erases the ID transmitting file no code is send out...How can i make that file so it can't be deleted or make that file CMS dependable. Anybody idea's?

Comment: At the end of the day, once your customer has a copy of your program on a machine that is under his control it will always be possible for him to reverse-engineer whatever you do: the best that you can hope for is to make it difficult through obfuscation.  If you cannot trust your customers to adhere to their licences (and aren't prepared to rely on legal mechanisms to enforce them), you will have to keep your software on machines that you control: e.g. provide your [software as a service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service), which is more trendily known as "cloud" these days.

Comment: yes, but in my experience a user want the code he buys. I could host everything myself so they can't see a single piece of code. But people don't want that. They want to "get" for what they pay.

Comment: In that case, your experience would appear to buck the general trend in the industry at the moment.  Also, why would they care about having a copy of the code that they have bought if it won't run without interacting with your server?  They may as well just access it on your server altogether!  Nevertheless, if you must give out your code, then (as I mentioned before) obfuscation and licence enforcement are the only tools in your armoury.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am wondering if it is possible to create a file within the cms, a php file, with a unique ID for every sale i made.

Yes, it's pretty easy to do it. Just create a file and include it in your php code.

> That file transmits a signal to a webserver with that ID.

No! That file will transmit an ID in http header to `YOUR` webserver. Not `a` webserver.

> So i can track the online versions of my cms.

Yes you can, until sysadmin check the log and see that their new cms is transmiting ID to your server. Then someone might ask why didn't you warn them, what else are you sending to your server, etc.

> But is it possible to make a cms dependable on that file... if a user erases the ID transmitting file no code is send out...

Yes, that's fairly easy. Just put some if (file) work, if (no_file) {dont work}.
And be prepared to obfuscate that code AS MUCH AS YOU CAN.
You are delivering PHP as source code and any descent programmer will deobfuscate almost any code.

> How can i make that file so it can't be deleted or make that file CMS dependable. Anybody idea's?

As far as I know, you can't. Almost anything can be deleted.
One idea is to create some nasty pgp public keys with some hashes that are calculated and recalculated all over your cms. But that will make your code hard to maintain and it will put some additional load to server...

Other solution is to put your code to your server. That's the only way to keep it safe.

p.s.
It would not be fair if I didn't mention that reading and editing (adding new features to someone's php code) if hard. It's really hard if code is bad (speaking from experience here). It's extremely hard if it's very, very bad code!
Many 'programmers' wouldn't touch core code of some app. 'Just gimme my framework...'
Obfuscated code is next to impossible to change if you don't have excellent coding skills + experience + lots of time.
Provided you really created your own cms (that's not an easy task) you will be able to create ok protection :) Some guide lines:

- never create 2 links. Always link 3 or more features (functions, classes, globals, etc) in some ludicrous way. One f() returns a resuls that is used in class that creates fake object which checks some global used in first f().
- use what you already have! but add some checks and tests with in. logical and illogical.
- use long time tests. In odd lunar months goto this {code}. In even goto this {code}.
- use different tests for same thing. copy/paste is search friendly.
- be shamelessly creative :)
- prepare yourself for your own traps. You are doomed without heavy documentation of your work.

Comment: No prob. I added some p.s.

Comment: @Johan CoR introduces some beginner obfuscation methods, but if you do this well it is going to be a problem for maintenance, need extra bug fixing including to those introduced by the obfuscation attempts themselves, and increased cost from longer development cycles. If you recruit new devs in the future, the downside of this will become even clearer. Without enforced licensing, this also does nothing to stop code being copied & used as you wanted. SaaS with code protected on the server is a good idea, or use a code protection tool with licensing. Disclosure: I am associated with ionCube.